# In WPF, how do I change the source of an image programatically?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a custom control with a default image that I want to change based on which iteration of the control it is. For example, I have one for "F1" and "NumLock" and so on. In the constructor of the control, I have this:

```cs
        public FixerBox(Dictionary<string,string> deets)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            btnOff();
            this.FixerTitle.Text = deets["Title"];
            this.FixerDesc.Text = deets["Description"];
            this.FixerTags.Text = deets["Tags"];
            this.FixerImg.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(deets["Img"], UriKind.Relative));
        }
```

The bitmap stuff was based on another answer and produces this:

[image: main window image showing custom control]

Below is the control itself showing that it's correctly getting the title, tags, and description, but the image is bunk (on the left side, that thin grey line is the border that should be around the image).c#

If I was using HTML/CSS, I could right-click the image to see what exactly its properties are, but I don't know how to get that kind of information using WPF. The best I could manage was in the top area is a status window where I've manually printed a "Tostring" output of the first controls image source data. Near as I can tell, it's all correct, but there's no actual image there. Every subsequent control has the same output (one thin line where the image should be).

EDIT Per comments, here is some more of the information. The main XAML file loads up the controls like so in its constructor:

```cs
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private Fixers fixers = new Fixers();
        // This is the custom control consisting mostly of various boxes
        private Dictionary<string,FixerBox> fixerBoxes = new Dictionary<string, FixerBox> { };

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var fixNames = fixers.FixerNames();
            foreach (string key in fixNames)
            {
                fixerBoxes[key] = new FixerBox(fixers.GetFix(key));
                FixersArea.Children.Add(fixerBoxes[key]);
            }

            StatusBox.Text += fixerBoxes["F1"].FixerImg.Source.ToString();
        }
    }
```

The fixers variable is of class Fixers which consists of the below (abbreviated to show just the F1 function for brevity):

```cs
class Fixers
    {

        private string ClearWS(string str)
        {
            var first = str.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "");
            return first.Replace("\t", "");
        }

        // Loads registry functions
        private Regis regStuff = new Regis();
        // Loads preferences from the file
        private Prefs prefs = new Prefs();
        // A timer to make sure the system behaves
        private Timer watcher;
        // Watcher action toggles
        private bool watchNumL = false;

        // Translation array from fix shortname to various data about them
        private Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> fixers = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>
        {
            ["F1"] = new Dictionary<string,string> {
                ["PrefName"] = "KillF1UnhelpfulHelp",
                ["Img"] = @"/graphics/F1key.png",
                ["Title"] = @"Diable F1 ""Help"" function",
                ["Description"] = @"
                    Have you ever hit the F1 key by accident and had a distracting and unhelpful window or webpage open as a result? 
                    Windows set the F1 key to a generic help function that basically never helps and always gets in the way. 
                    Enable this control to disable that obnoxious design choice. Note that some programs still respond to F1 on their own accord, 
                    but this will stop the default Windows behavior in things like Windows Explorer at least.
                    ",
                ["Tags"] = "#Keyboard,#Rage"
            },
        };

        public Fixers()
        {
            // The readability hack above with multi-line strings introduces a bunch of extra whitespace. Let's clear that out
            foreach (var fixKey in fixers.Keys)
            {
                fixers[fixKey]["Description"] = ClearWS(fixers[fixKey]["Description"]);
            }
        }

        public List<string> FixerNames()
        {
            return fixers.Keys.ToList();
        }

        public bool IsFixed(string which)
        {
            // If we're watching, it's fixed
            if ("NumL" == which) return watchNumL;

            // For anything registry related
            return regStuff.IsFixed(which);
        }

        public Dictionary<string,string> GetFix(string which)
        {
            return fixers[which];
        }
    }
```

Comment: What you are showing here seems inconsistent. There is a `pack://application` image URI in the screenshot, which could however not be created by `new Uri(deets["Img"], UriKind.Relative)`. It would have thrown an exception saying that a relative URI could not be created. Are you sure that the code you are showing is executed at all?

Comment: That is the output. The value of deets["Img"] is /graphics/F1key.png. No errors or warnings.

Comment: You may want to show us the relevant parts of the XAML.

Comment: Edited. Also, I verified that the images in my subfolder are added to the project. Or rather, I right-clicked them and it only shows "exclude from project" and not "include" which tells me they're already in there?

Comment: That is no XAML. We need to see the XAML of the FixerBox class. It would also be helpful to see the relevant XAML parts of the MainWindow, e.g. what FixersArea is.

Comment: And of course make sure that the image files like `F1key.png` are located in a project folder named `graphics` and that their Build Action is set to `Resource`. Then load them from a Resource File Pack URI like `FixerImg.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,," + deets["Img"]))`;

Comment: That was it. I didn't know you could set their "build action" in that way. I've made the change and it works fine now. If you leave it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score -1):

if you use binding, you can create in your ViewModel a string, in which is stored the path of your image, then you can easily change programatically its path.

Then in XAML just bind image's source to the string.

In my case I have a list of objects, with the property `ImageName' :

```
<Image Source="{Binding DataContext.SelectedMacro.ImageName,   
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"/>
```

Comment: What I'm doing is generating a series of controls on start each with it's own data and image. I'm not trying to change the images during runtime (though I will for one specific control and will keep this in mind).